# Spearwall and Overwhelm

Tags: battle-brothers

In Battle Brothers, does the attacks from the spearwall trigger the overwhelmed status if you start it with a high initiative?

Are there any other auto-attacks that can benefit from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simmilar question was asked on Steam forum. [Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/365360/discussions/0/135510393196801668/)

> It shouldn't. Overhwelm only works on targets which act after the guy overwhelming them in the same turn.

Shortly: **No.**